# Inter-thread communication in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading, opengl, glut

I have two threads (the applications main thread and another one). I am using OpenGL to draw some stuff and I am using the OpenGL keyboard and mouse callbacks. OpenGL blocks when I call glutMainLoop() and since I have to do some calculations in the background, I created another thread. Now, the OpenGL callbacks shall send some data (e.g. x, y position of the mouse/key which has been pressed) to the other thread which has a critical section. While the critical section is running no messages should be accepted, but rather than dropping these messages, I want to process them after the critical section. The class of the non-OpenGL looks something like this:

```
void run()
{
    for (;;) {
        int currentTime = now();
        if (now() - previousTime > WAIT_INTERVAL) {
            previousTime = currentTime;
            tick();
        }
    }
}

void tick() {
    // critical section begins
    processor->step()
    // critical section ends
}

void receiveMessage(void *data) {
    processor->changeSomeData(data);
}
```

So, if receiveMessage() is called from the OpenGL thread and processor->step() is running, the call to changeSomeData() should be postponed because it would mess up the whole calculation.

I want to use the following classes to synchronize the threads:

Mutex.h:

```
#ifndef MUTEX_H
#define MUTEX_H

#include <Windows.h>

class Mutex;

#include "Lock.h"

class Mutex
{
public:
    Mutex();
    ~Mutex();
private:
    void acquire();
    void release();

    CRITICAL_SECTION criticalSection;

    friend class Lock;
};


#endif
```

Mutex.cpp:

```
#include "Mutex.h"

Mutex::Mutex()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&this->criticalSection);
}

Mutex::~Mutex()
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&this->criticalSection);
}

void Mutex::acquire()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&this->criticalSection);
}

void Mutex::release()
{
    LeaveCriticalSection(&this->criticalSection);
}
```

Lock.h:

```
#ifndef LOCK_H
#define LOCK_H

class Lock;

#include "Mutex.h"

class Lock
{
public:
    Lock(Mutex& mutex);
    ~Lock();
private:
    Mutex &mutex;
};

#endif
```

Lock.cpp

```
#include "Lock.h"

Lock::Lock(Mutex& mutex) : mutex(mutex)
{
    this->mutex.acquire();
}

Lock::~Lock ()
{
    this->mutex.release();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole project: http://upload.visusnet.de/uploads/BlobbyWarriors-rev30.zip (~180 MB)

**EDIT 2:**

And here is the SVN repo: https://projects.fse.uni-due.de/svn/alexander-mueller-bloby-warriors/trunk/

Comment: How can I do it? I tried adding a Mutex object to the non-OpenGL thread class and I've added Lock lock(mutex) right before the critical section and to the beginning of receiveMessage(), but these sections aren't mutually excluded.

Comment: It's hard to follow the explanation of your problem. Can you post some more code that shows exactly where your RAII Lock class is being instantiated? Also, please post a stub of the other thread (the one running the OpenGL code) and show where your locks are inserted there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh... No, no, no. **Threads are NOT what you should use here.** Seriously. Thread are NOT your solution in this particular case. Let's roll back a bit...

You're using GLUT at the moment and you say you need threads to "avoid locking on `glutMainLoop()`. And you don't want locking because you want to do some calculations in the meantime.

Stop now and ask yourself - **are you sure that those operations need to be done asynchronically (as a whole) from OpenGL rendering?** If so, you may stop reading this post and look at the other ones, but I sincerely believe that it may not be the case for a +- typical real-time OpenGL application.

So... A typical OpenGL app looks like this:

- handle events
- tick calculations
- redraw screen

Most GL window libraries let you implement that as your own main loop, GLUT kind of obfuscates that with its "callbacks", but the idea is the same.

You can still introduce parallelism in your application, but it should start and stop at step 2, so it's still sequential on main-loop level: "calculate a frame of calculations, THEN render this frame". This approach is likely to *save you a lot of trouble*.

Protip: Change your library. GLUT is outdated and not maintained anymore. Switching to GLFW (or SDL) for window creation wouldn't take much effort in terms of code and - contrary to GLUT - you define your main loop yourself, which seems to be what you want to achieve here. (Plus they tend to be more convenient for input & window event handling, etc.)

---

Some typical pseudocode with constant-timestep real-time physics without interfering with rendering (assuming that you want to run physics more often than rendering, in general):

```
var accum = 0
const PHYSICS_TIMESTEP = 20
while (runMainLoop) {
    var dt = getTimeFromLastFrame

    accum += dt
    while (accum > PHYSICS_TIMESTEP) {
        accum -= PHYSICS_TIMESTEP
        tickPhysicsSimulation(PHYSICS_TIMESTEP)
    }

    tickAnyOtherLogic(dt)
    render()
}
```

A possible extension from that is to use the value of `accum` as an additional "extrapolation" value only for rendering, which would allow for visually smooth the graphical representation while simulating physics more seldomly (with bigger DT), possibly more seldomly than once per rendering frame.

Comment: My previous versions used the main loop for the calculations, but that decreased the FPS a lot. The calculations I have to do are physics calculations. What I am trying to do is rendering the physics world in another thread so that graphics are decoupled from physics.

Comment: ... and the main problem is that the physics calculations MUST be done in an interval which needs to be the same all the time. I am adding the whole source code to my initial post...

Comment: Having the graphics and physics decoupled is certainly useful, but it's still not something which would benefit from multithreading.

Comment: I've edited my post to show how it's usually done without multithreading.

Comment: The problem that if rendering is very slow for some frames, the physics calculations are delayed, still exists. That is why I want to decouple it with threads. So, if rendering is slow, physics calculations are still correct (would look like frame dropping) and if the physics calculations are slow, the rendering still looks okay (would look like lagging).

Comment: Isn't that the case with the code I posted? If rendering takes a lot of time, then in the next frame you'll still have as many iterations of physics simulation with constant DT as you actually require - plus, you avoid the additional cost of synchronization. Also note that the OpenGL calls are actually asynchronous and won't block unless you call glFinish().

Comment: Before I make more assumptions I am going to test your proposal. Later on, I'll restart complaining. ;-)

Comment: So... I have implemented it with your code... It does not work as expected. I have added the SVN address to my initial post, so you can browse the current code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The most obvious thing I noticed is in your deltaTime calculation - `this->previousTicks` should be set to the new value right after calculating deltaTime, and you're doing many calculations between them, thus "omitting" a lot of time. Have a look: http://pastebin.com/fmSvuAFT

Comment: Okay. Awesome. Seems to work now... It's not perfect, but the best solution I had.

Answer (score 1):

In the main thread:  lock a mutex, add a struct/object containing the necessary info to a FIFO data structure of some sort, unlock the mutex, then (optionally) wake up the background thread (via a signal or a condition variable or writing a byte to a socket or however)

In the background thread:  (optionally) block until awoken by the main thread, then lock the mutex, pop the first item from the head of the FIFO, unlock the mutex, process the item, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Critical sections and mutexes are bad.  They should only be used by library designers, and usually not even then (because for reusable code, it's often worth the extra effort to gain the extra scalability of lock-free).

Instead, you should use a threadsafe queue.  Windows offers lots:

- thread message queue (`PostMessage`)
- mailslots
- message-mode pipes
- datagram sockets
- SList API

are just a few of your options.

All of these are highly optimized and much easier to use than designing your own queue.

Comment: I think your first paragraph comes off as a little bit crazy.  Maybe not for the highest-level code and certainly not for untrained developers, but mutexes are a fact of life for many types of development.

Comment: "Critical sections and mutexes are bad."  I couldn't disagree more.

Comment: @up - that approach (which indeed may sound funny) has something to do with a MT paradigm called "lock free", I suppose.

Comment: @John: depends on what you compare them to. They *are* bad. It's just that sometimes, no non-bad alternative exists. ;) they're a lousy way to implementing synchronization. Non-composable and error-prone, what's not to love about them? ;) I don't think @Ben meant that attempting to implement concurrency *without* synchronization was to be preferred.

Comment: @jalf:  put that way, I see what you mean.  yeah, I agree with that now.

Comment: Thanks @jalf.  It's not that monitors should NEVER be used, it's that they're not applicable to more problems than other synchronization elements (such as events or completion queues), yet seem to get used in 99% of concurrent scenarios. (Application of Bayes's theorem suggests that 80% of times you see a mutex in code, it was the wrong tool.) I blame language support: Java's `synchronized` keyword and C#'s `lock` keyword both tell programmers that monitors are **the** way to synchronize, a horrible lie.  The horrible brokenness of e.g. `System.Collections.HashTable.Synchronized` doesn't help.

Comment: It's probably all part of a conspiracy to keep old parallel programmers getting paid well by telling CS students that you can effectively add concurrency externally.  You can't.  [The set of operations that make sense for a concurrent data structure is different from operations for use in a sequential execution model.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/12/10/the-file-system-is-unpredictable.aspx)  The result: asveikau thinks that because so many people use it (<quote>It's a fact of life</quote>, it must be the right thing to do.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - I feel like you've mischaracterized my comment slightly. I'm well aware of the limitations of locks and related difficulties, and I've worked with lock-free synchronization as well.  I just think it's a bit crazy to say that a lock shouldn't ever be used.  For many uses they are the most practical tool and you'd be unlikely to see the downsides in practice.  Of course it all depends on your application.

Comment: What do we mean by "a lock" though? Many alternate synchronization mechanisms *use locks internally*, but present different abstractions to the programmer. Transactional Memory is an example of this. So there's a wide middle area  between "using locks" and "using lock-free synchronization". There's a whole range of "using locks, but wrapped up so you don't see them, and don't have to deal with their flaws". It's not simply "lock or no lock".

Comment: @jalf: That's what I meant by "used by library designers".

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using GLUT anymore - it's terribly outdated and very restrictive. But if you're set on using it, you might want to look into [glutIdleFunc](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glutIdleFunc.3GLUT.html). GLUT will continuously invoke this callback when it's idle - you can use this to perform background processing in the main thread.